# get 5 random favorites from flickr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random, flickr, favorites

I need to retrieve 5 random favorites photos from a flickr profile.

I've got perfect [Moonpix-Flickr Gem](http://github.com/moonpxi/flickr) to work with Flickr API.

And it works great, by using method *.favorites* I can get full list of user's favorites photos.

It returns as *Flickr::PhotoCollection* and I don't know how to get 5 random records from it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, guys, I've just had a hit

```
user.favorites.sort_by{rand}[0..4]
```